Name of a 1cm 8 pin power connector
I saw that the Dell poweredge r720 uses a similar connector than the GPUs (the 8 pin connector that comes with the PSU) for the disks power board, but this is smaller (like half the size). Anyone knows its name, and if I can buy a cable somewhere? (it would be better if it's an adapter from this connector to the "big" 8 pin PSU connector)

Thanks.

Be very careful with connector pinouts in Dell computers: they have a reputation for not following standards.

@AndrewMorton I had in mind to check the voltage before disconnecting everything, but thanks for the advice

This is a Molex Micro-Fit 3.0, specifically part number 430250800.
You can make your own connector assembly with that housing and 8 pieces of the 2039510001 female crimp terminal.
If you want to avoid crimping the contacts yourself, Molex also sells the ready-made 2147561082 cable assembly. It's widely available at distributors.
